# UIImageView change animation left to right

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, uiviewanimation, uianimation

How do perform a change animation to a UIImageView from left to right. Here is the code I have so far, but this causes a weird flip animation, how can make it a smooth left to right animation like in facebook pitures.

```
    UIImage toImage = new UIImage((string)ListOfImages[imageIndex]);
    UIView.Transition(this.ImageView,
                      duration: 1.0,
                      options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft,
                      animation: () => this.ImageView.Image = toImage,
                      completion: null);
```

Comment: Options for animations  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions

Answer (score 0):

**from left to right** do you mean you want to change the `UIImageView`'s position(Frame)? If so you can try `UIView.Animate()`:

```
UIView.Animate(1.0, () =>
{
    this.ImageView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 300, 300, 300);

}, () =>
{
    this.ImageView.Image = toImage;
});
```